# Show captcha to user with Python

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, tkinter, captcha

The **init** of my code is basically to setup Chrome, get the url and login with the credentials given in the tKinter GUI. When I almost finished the code I'v added `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` to make the GUI work without open the brownser, because others co-workers will make use of it and not just me.

The problem is that sometimes the login part asks for a Captcha resolve, so I think that the best way to handle with It is to open just the captcha to the user resolve, close it and continue to run the code, Is that right?

I'v been searching about It and was not able to understand what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer and too long for a comment.

You can achieve it by opening the browser just for the captcha for user to complete but as we know once the options are selected and assigned to the driver, they cannot be manipulated later which means changing an ongoing web browser from headless to normal is not possible.

*So here is what you can do,*

1. Start the program with a headless browser.
2. A function to check whether the site is asking for the captcha.
3. If yes, then [save the cookies](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-cookies/) of the current browser and close the headless browser.
4. Reopen a new browser without `--headless` argument using those cookies you saved.
5. Wait for the user to complete the captcha and let the site redirect or load after doing captcha.
6. Fetch the cookies of current browser and close it.
7. Finally reopen a new browser with `--headless` argument and use those cookies.

---

There might be some better approach of doing this but this will work very well if implemented correctly.